# how to validate html form with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to validate an input before I include another PHP so the user can get the error on the same page if there's one.. 4 inputs are required but the others are optional.. what I want to do is if the user only fill in the 4 required inputs validate the inputs than include another PHP file (instead of including the PHP I put a JavaScript instead to alert me that the code functions well..) and if the user also fill in the other optional inputs to also validate them and include a PHP file the problem I'm having is that it still alert me the code is good even when the user inserts invalid characters.
I only want it to process the last JavaScript if the user fills in the inputs with the allowed characters..

Here's the PHP:

```
   <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$titleErr = $MdescripErr = $posterErr = $vcodeErr = $vcode2Err = $vcode3Err = $mlink1Err = $mlink2Err = $mlink3Err = "";
$title = $Mdescrip = $poster = $comment = $vcode = $vcode2 = $vcode3 = $mlink1 = $comment = $mlink2 = $mlink3 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["title"]))
     {$titleErr = "title is required";}
   else
     {
     $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/",$title))
       {
       $titleErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["Mdescrip"]))
     {$MdescripErr = "Movie Description is required";}
   else
     {
     $Mdescrip = test_input($_POST["Mdescrip"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/",$Mdescrip))
       {
       $MdescripErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }


   if (empty($_POST["poster"]))
     {$posterErr = "Poster Link is required";}
   else
     {
     $poster = test_input($_POST["poster"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$poster))
       {
       $posterErr = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["vcode"]))
     {$vcodeErr = "Embed Link is required";}
   else
     {
     $vcode = test_input($_POST["vcode"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$vcode))
       {
       $vcodeErr = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }


    if (empty($_POST["vcode2"]))
     {$vcode2 = "";}
   else
     {
     $vcode2 = test_input($_POST["vcode2"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$vcode2))
       {
       $vcode2Err = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["vcode3"]))
     {$vcode3 = "";}
   else
     {
     $vcode3 = test_input($_POST["vcode3"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$vcode3))
       {
       $vcode3Err = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["mlink1"]))
     {$mlink1 = "";}
   else
     {
     $mlink1 = test_input($_POST["mlink1"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$mlink1))
       {
       $mlink1Err = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["mlink2"]))
     {$mlink2 = "";}
   else
     {
     $mlink2= test_input($_POST["mlink2"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$mlink2))
       {
       $mlink2Err = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["mlink3"]))
     {$mlink3 = "";}
   else
     {
     $mlink3 = test_input($_POST["mlink3"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$mlink3))
       {
       $mlink3Err = "Invalid URL"; 
       }
     }


}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}

if ($title == NULL || $Mdescrip == NULL || $poster == NULL || $vcode == NULL)
{
}
else if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/",$title) ||!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/",$Mdescrip) || !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$poster) || !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$vcode))
{
}
else
     {
?>
<script>

alert("it went through");

</script>
<?php
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to split the url and remove the unnecesary items like "https://" so you can take one url like "http://www.stackoverflow.com/bla/bla/bla" and split it into ["http","","www.stackoverflow.com","bla","bla","bla"] 
And finally check if each element is set(valid),  this will make your validation quite simple